# How can I build/install software on an embedded system?

Tags: linux, software-installation, compiling, embedded

I am working on a device that runs some kind of Unix/Linux on ARM architecture. The manufacturers of this device have provided me with a 'debugging tool' that connects to my PC via USB. Using Tera Term I can then connect to a terminal interface on the device.

I can't seem to easily transfer files between my PC and the device using the debugging tool, as the device doesn't support ZMODEM or any of the other file transfer protocols that Tera Term has. The device does, however, have a USB port. If a FAT32 USB storage device is inserted into this it is automatically mounted into /mnt/usb/sda1. Using this I can copy files to/from the device.

The device does not seem to have any package manager installed. (No `yum`, no `apt-get` and not even `dpkg`.) It doesn't have a text editor installed (as far as I can tell) and is lacking some basic Linux/Unix commands too, such as `tee`, `who`, `whoami`, `less`, `id` or `man`.

There's no FTP or SSH server installed. In absence of a package manager, I tried to compile OpenSSH (and dependencies, zlib and LibreSSL) from source on it, but `make` isn't present. (zlib's configure script also needed a bit of tweaking to work without `tee`)

In terms of trying to work out what distro I have, the command `lsb_release` is not found, nor is `uname`, and there's no files ending in '-release' in /etc. In /proc/version I can find that the kernel version is 3.10.27 and the GCC version was "4.8.2 20131014 (prerelease) (Linaro GCC 4.8-2013.10)".

I have root access to the device.

So my question is, how can I install software on this? Being able to set up OpenSSH would be very valuable to me, but without 'make' I feel like it's a chicken and egg problem.

Comment: You'll need to ask the device manufacturer directly. They probably disabled the ability to build/install any additional software deliberately - whether that was a good idea or not is unrelated to the fact that they did so.

Comment: You don't run `make` on embedded targets like this. You need a cross-compiling development environment, consisting of things like the Linaro toolchain. That is run on some development box. Then you get the built files onto the target somehow, like copying from the USB drive. (By that means you can get ssh, zmodem (sz/rz) and other things on there).

Comment: If it's arm you can probably find pre-compiled binaries (look at dropbear for something "simpler" than openssh) for it. Pull a binary *from* the device and run readelf/file against it on your local machine. FWIW it's probably running busybox.

Comment: @drewbenn I'm having trouble finding pre-compiled binaries, any advice on where I should look?

Comment: @Kaz, that makes sense. I've only worked with Linux on servers before, so when I couldn't use package management my instinct was to compile from source. Could you please give me a bit of an overview of how I cross-compile something? My dev machine runs Win10/Ubuntu 14.04. The device has a "ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)" processor according to /proc/cpuinfo. Any good articles or tutorials to help me get up and running? Thanks!

Comment: @drewbenn It does indeed appear to be busybox, good guess!

Comment: Not really a guess, busybox is pretty standard for embedded systems, I was just trying to give you some search bait. I'd try some Debian binaries, actually (maybe `armhf` architecture?); fetch a deb and expand it locally and copy the binaries to the target (grep or [dropbear](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/armhf/dropbear/download) might be an okay place to start). You may need to copy the system's interpreter (listed if you run `file` on a binary, which is why I suggested pulling a binary from the system) to wherever your new binaries expect it.

Comment: Oh and if they gave you a system, that's technically a distribution, which means they're legally obligated to give you the source code including patches they used and the build environment or instructions to set it up, and instructions to load the code, for any GPLv2 or later stuff (which includes busybox and the Linux kernel). It sounds like you may be approaching this as more of a challenge, and also certain vendors are pretty obstinate when it comes to their legal obligations, but they *should* have already given you everything you need, so you could try asking them....

Comment: There's a language barrier between me and the vendor, which means it is often easier to do things myself.

Comment: Just to provide a status update, I have managed to cross-compile Dropbear and have run it on the target system. Just working out how to set it up now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could one of you please post what you've written in your comment(s) as an answer? Between the two of you you've helped me solve this issue.

Comment: If neither drewebenn nor Kaz, get around to posting an answer, I'd suggest that you answer the question yourself (which you can accept). This would help future readers in a similar situation know what to do when they're searching on the Internet. BTW, this question was suggested for closure as "too broad" but I think it's useful and upvoted it, instead.